# Handling error response in Retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit as my networking library. Everything is running smoothly. 
I just have a new requirement, Server send me a **response** in Json, in case of **failure**.
I want to grab that whole response, right now **RetrofitError** in failure callback, doesn't give my server response in any of the **RetrofitError** attributes.

Any Kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: don't you get the response inside the RetrofitError?

Comment: @blackbelt I do, but its parsed
for example if the response was "Item not found"
it will give me "not found" I want the raw response from http

Comment: what are you trying to get out of the response? something from some json retruned by your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to get are the fields from the json response returned from your api during a failure. I think the process for a failure is pretty similar to the process for a success. First, your response object needs to have a field to map to the json error field, or any field that you want to extract from the response (success or failure). In the success case you get the converted response back directly, but in the case of a failure, you need to  call getResponse() on the returned RetofitError object to get the converted response, and then extract the returned data.

Here is an example.

I have a rails backend that responds with a token when successful or a list of errors if not successful.  Here is the rails controller method if that helps, but the bottom line is there is a json entry errors that I want to examine if the create fails.

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in_api(@user)
      render json: { token: @issued_remember_token }, status: 201
    else
      render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }  , status: 406
    end
  end
```

Here is my retrofit call

```
    @POST(API_URL + "/signup")
    void signup(@Body UserRequestParams requestParams,
            Callback<SignupResponse> tokenParms);
```

and here is my  SignupResponse object

```
public class SignupResponse extends BaseResponse {
    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

}

public class BaseResponse {
    private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Boolean mSuccessful = false;
    public Response getRawResponse() {
        return rawResponse;
    }

    public void setRawResponse(Response rawResponse) {
        this.rawResponse = rawResponse;
    }

    private Response rawResponse;


    public BaseResponse() {
        super();
    }

    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setSuccessful(Boolean successful) {
        mSuccessful = successful;
    }

    public Boolean isSuccessful() {
        return mSuccessful;
    }
}
```

The result is that retrofit fills in the errors field as part of the callback process, same as if it were a success.  Now I can just check to see if the response was successful or not and call the appropriate methods on the response object.  errors will be null if it were successful but valid if not.

For completeness here are the other two methods/classes involved in my example.

```
    @Subscribe
    public void onSignup(SignupRequest event) {
        System.out.println("inside api repo - making signup request");
        mRailsApi.signup(event, new RailsApiCallback<SignupResponse>(mBus, new SignupResponse()));
    }


public class RailsApiCallback<T extends BaseResponse> implements Callback<T> {

    private Bus mBus;
    private T mResponse;

    public RailsApiCallback(Bus bus, T response) {
        super();
        mBus = bus;
        mResponse = response;     
    }

    @Override 
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        System.out.println(retrofitError.toString());
        T response = retrofitError != null && retrofitError.getBody() != null ? (T) retrofitError.getBody() : mResponse  ;
        response.setRawResponse(retrofitError.getResponse());
        response.setSuccessful(false);
        System.out.println("posting response to bus");
        mBus.post(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void success(T convertedResponse, Response rawResponse) {
        System.out.println(rawResponse.getBody());
        T response = convertedResponse != null ? convertedResponse : mResponse ;
        response.setSuccessful(true);
        response.setRawResponse(rawResponse);
        mBus.post(response);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very detailed answer, thats what I wanted.